# iOS BLE reconnection failed

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, reconnect

I have a problems for **reconnecting** to **bluetooth device** in iphone.
When I connect to BLE device at first, I can connect to it successfully.
But after disconnect, and I will try to connect that device again, then connect and disconnect soon.
I got the following log:
"Started scanning for devices ...
Connected to device: !
Scanning stopped
Disconnected device"

Please help me!

Comment: This will highly depend on what you code is. For example, do you ever call `cancelPeripheralConnection` (which would create that behavior)? There are numerous issues that could lead to this kind of behavior. It really depends on what you've done. Try pulling your connection code into a new project (so it's very simple and you don't have to worry about complicated UI) and just focus on connection and reconnection. That hopefully will lead you to a more specific question.

Comment: I called this function to disconnect from _peripheral

Comment: if peripheral.services != nil {

Comment: for service: CBService in (peripheral.services!) {

Comment: if service.characteristics != nil { 

                    for characteristic:CBCharacteristic in service.characteristics! { 

                        if characteristic.isNotifying { 

                            peripheral.setNotifyValue(false, for: characteristic) 

                        } 

                    } 
                } 
            } 
        } 
        
        centralManager.cancelPeripheralConnection(peripheral)

Comment: Please put any code you want to include in the question in the question; it's very difficult to understand in comments.